# python RE and list processing

Tags: python

I've a file like below

```
ElapsedTime2.68s: PlaceOrder
ElapsedTime2.69s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime0.11s: GetOrderList
ElapsedTime0.11s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime2.10s: PlaceOrder
ElapsedTime2.11s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime0.10s: GetOrderList
ElapsedTime0.10s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime2.00s: PlaceOrder
ElapsedTime2.01s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime0.28s: GetOrderList
ElapsedTime0.28s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime1.64s: PlaceOrder
ElapsedTime1.65s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime0.11s: GetOrderList
ElapsedTime0.11s: ClassARestCAll
ElapsedTime1.99s: PlaceOrder
ElapsedTime2.01s: ClassARestCAll
```

How can I parse the file to get this result?

```
               average   min   max
ClassARestCAll    1.23   0.1  2.69
GetOrderList      0.15   0.1  0.28
PlaceOrder       2.082  1.64  2.68
```

I've developed one approach to solve it using RE and List operation.
However my approach scan the whole list once for every new method name.

How can we  get stats for all API names  by scanning the list only ONCE.

```
import re

def get_stats(N, p_api):
    list_of_rt = []
    for line in N:
        y= re.split("\s+", line)
        if y[1] == p_api:
             curr_rt = float(y[0][11:-2])
             list_of_rt.append(curr_rt)

    min_rt ,max_rt = min(list_of_rt), max(list_of_rt)
    total_rt, total_cnt = sum(list_of_rt), len(list_of_rt)
    print p_api, min_rt, max_rt, "%.3f" %round(total_rt/total_cnt,3), total_cnt


ifile = open('data1.txt','r').read()
api_rts= re.findall(r'ElapsedTime\d*.\d*s: \S*',ifile)


list_of_api_names = []
for api_rt in api_rts:
    y= re.split("\s+", api_rt)
    list_of_api_names.append(y[1])

#get distinct list of API names

distinct_apis = set(list_of_api_names)

print 'api         min,   max,   average,  total occurences'

# for each API name call get_stat

for api in distinct_apis:
    get_stats(api_rts ,api)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet :3?

Comment: Yes I did. Here is the output of my program: api         min,   max,   average,  total occurences
GetOrderList 0.1 0.28 0.150 4
PlaceOrder 1.64 2.68 2.082 5
ClassARestCAll 0.1 2.69 1.230 9

Comment: Your ``re.findall(r'ElapsedTime\d*.\d*s: \S*',ifile)`` just do the same as ``open('data1.txt','r').readlines()'' (or ``.....readlines().strip()`` if there were whitespaces at the beginning and end of each line).

Comment: The dot in the RE pattern ``r'ElapsedTime\d*.\d*s: \S*'`` means **'every character, except newline'**. If you want to mean **'one dot'**, you must write ``r'ElapsedTime\d*\.\d*s: \S*'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

rgx = re.compile('ElapsedTime(\d*\.\d*)s: (\S*)')

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

with open('data1.txt','r') as f:
    for m in rgx.finditer(f.read()):
        d[m.group(2)].append(float(m.group(1)))

lapi = max(map(len,d.iterkeys()))

print '{: ^{width}}   min    max    average   total occurences'.format('api',width=lapi)
pat = '{0:%d}   {1:.2f}   {2:.2f}   {3:.3f}     {4}' % lapi
print '\n'.join(pat.format(api,min(li),max(li),sum(li)/len(li),len(li))
                for api,li in d.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, numpy
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('data1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        l =  re.findall('([\d.]+|\w+$)', line)
        data[l[1]].append(float(l[0]))

metrics = [ ['avg', numpy.average], ['min',min], ['max',max] ]
summary = defaultdict(dict)
for k,l in data.items():
    summary[k] = { m[0] : m[1](l) for m in metrics }

print " " * 17 + "\t".join("%-5s" % m[0] for m in metrics)
for k, s in summary.items():
    print "%-15s: " % k + "\t".join("%.3f" % s[m[0]] for m in metrics)
```